# Catch UIWebview reloads

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

is there any way to get informed, when a UIWebview has loaded a new page?
The documentation doesn't list a delegate for this.In my case, I want to know, when UIWebview is done with navigation in iUI pages.

Best Regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... what Morion said, only I think this method might be more along the lines of what he is looking for:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

It gets called every time the user clicks on a link.

Please see the UIWebViewDelegate docs:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 4):

variant A: i cannot understand what do you want.
variant B: you didn't see method like

> ```
> - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
> ```

it is called every time webview finishes loading new content

Answer (score 1):

the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` message is sent to the delegate every time the webview loads a new page. So you should try there.